# Shortcut changing in LibreOffice (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, language, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm writing in Hebrew and Arabic with LibreOffice. Say I want to toggle bold so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> turns into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>נ</kbd>  (nun in Hebrew). So if I'd like to toggle bold I will need to change lang to English then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> then change back to Hebrew.

I'd like to add another shortcut or to change the shortcut (say to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>נ</kbd> for bold instand Ctrl + <kbd>B</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Reference [LibreOffice Help - Keyboard](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Keyboard#Modify)

> **Keyboard**
>
> Assigns or edits the shortcut keys for LibreOffice commands, or
>   LibreOffice Basic macros.
>
> Choose `Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard tab` (a document must be
>   opened)
>
> You can assign or edit shortcut keys for the current application or
>   for all LibreOffice applications.
>
> Avoid assigning shortcut keys that are currently used by your
>   operating system.
>
> **Modify**
>
> - Assigns the key combination selected in the Shortcut keys list to the command selected in the Function list.
> - Deletes the selected element or elements without requiring confirmation.

Comment: Yeah, it wont let me assign shortcuts to hebrow or arabic